Use original image size and aspect ratio in the carousel component in Django CMS
I am using the carousel component for Django CMS from the front-end plugins.
I have a problem with the image size and aspect ratio. I tried an approach to manage the CSS file according to this source:
Maintain image aspect ratio in carousel
However, this is not solving my problem. The image is still being cropped and downsampled, resulting in low resolution.
I want to display the images in full view and in their original aspect ratio. However, the carousel component from the plugin only allows the use of fixed aspect ratios, which do not correspond to my image aspect ratio. I didn’t find the possibility to use or select the image’s original aspect ratio.

Moreover, it seems that the carousel component loads a downsampled and cropped version of the image.
If I understood correctly, the image loading response is from the thumbnail component:
djangocms_frontend/contrib/carousel/templates/djangocms_frontend/bootstrap5/carousel/default/image.html
{% load cms_tags easy_thumbnails_tags %}
{% if instance.rel_image %}
    {% thumbnail instance.rel_image options.size crop=options.crop upscale=options.upscale subject_location=instance.rel_image.subject_location as thumbnail %}

    <img class="d-block w-100" src="{{ thumbnail.url }}" alt="{{ instance.rel_image.default_alt_text|default:'' }}" />
{% else %}
    <div class="d-block w-100"
        style="aspect-ratio: {{ aspect_ratio }}">
        {% for plugin in instance.child_plugin_instances %}
            {% render_plugin plugin %}
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
{% endif %}

My questions are:

How to display a full-width, uncropped image with responsive height in the Django CMS carousel component?

OR

How can I configure the carousel or thumbnail components to load images with their original size and aspect ratio?

Thank you for your valuable assistance!

Firstly, I think this is a bug: Images are always rendered 1024x768 no matter what. I'd encourage you to raise an issue here: https://github.com/django-cms/djangocms-frontend/issues
However, there is a solution to this by providing custom templates:

On your template path, copy the three files carousel.html, image.html, slide.html from within the djangocms_frontend/contrib/carousel app into a folder djangocms_frontend/bootstrap5/carousel/default somewhere on your template path, ideally before the original templates. Now you can customize the templates. (If you do not want to overwrite the templates for all carousels, name the last folder, say, preserve-ar.)

Remove the creation of thumbnails by adjusting image.html:
{% load cms_tags %}
{% if instance.rel_image %}
    <img class="d-block w-100" src="{{ instance.rel_image.url }}" alt="{{ instance.rel_image.default_alt_text|default:'' }}" />
{% else %}
    <div class="d-block w-100"
        style="aspect-ratio: {{ aspect_ratio }}">
        {% for plugin in instance.child_plugin_instances %}
            {% render_plugin plugin %}
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
{% endif %}

This will have each slide occupy full width (due to the w-100 class) and height according to their actual size. This leads to the carousel changing its height with each image - normally undesirable. At this point, you should have answered your first question.

If you want to fix the height of all the images, you can set it in the template, e.g. <img class="d-block mx-auto" style="height: 50vh; ..." sets the height of the image to 50% of the viewport's height. The mx-auto class adds the needed margins to the left and right. Now you have the images in their original aspect ration with fixed height - your second question.

If you decided not to overwrite the default templates, but to add your own, you'll have to let djangocms-frontend know by adding something like this to your settings.py:
DJANGOCMS_FRONTEND_CAROUSEL_TEMPLATES = (
    ("default", _("Default")),
    ("preserve-ar", _("Preserve aspect ratio")),
)

This will allow you to select which carousel template will be used in the carousel plugin.


Hope this helps!

Thank you @Fabian for your answer. I myself already tried the image.html overriding. But your answer is more complete. Thank you. I will try your suggestions.

About reporting the issue, just, I didn't think that it is bug... It seems, that I should report this. Thank you @Fabian for pointing this out.
